# Comparing the length of two similar strings and picking the longest

Tags: sql-server, sql-like

I am Trying to compare two strings and pick the longest if they are similar, I have managed to pick the longest by using the following code:

```
SELECT D.RID, ProductID, Product, [Length] FROM (
SELECT RID, MAX([Length]) AS theLength FROM SortData GROUP BY RID)
AS X INNER JOIN SortData AS D ON D.RID = X.RID AND D.[Length] = X.theLength
```

But I am now trying to make sure that the code only pick the longest string if it is a like the word it is comparing it to, I have attempted the following code in a few ways but I would be grateful if somebody could help me:

```
SELECT D.RID, D.ProductID, Product, [Length] FROM (
SELECT RID, Product, MAX([Length]) AS theLength FROM SortData GROUP BY RID)
AS X INNER JOIN SortData AS D ON D.RID = X.RID AND D.[Length] = X.theLength WHERE
D.Product LIKE Product
```

Using this code I get the Following Error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Column 'SortData.Product' is
>   invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Msg 209, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 5 Ambiguous column name 'Product'. Msg 209, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 2 Ambiguous column name 'Product'.

Example of the Data I would Like to pick:

1 Sam
1 Samantha
2 Oliver
3 Ollie
4 Benjamin
4 Ben
...
I would expect the output list to be like:

1 Samantha
2 Oliver
3 Ollie
4 Benjamin
...

To Clarify what I am trying to do in the context of this example, I am trying to compare the two Names and if the are LIKE (e.g. x.Name LIKE Name) then pick the longest...

As Requested here is further test data:

1 Hydrogen
1 Hydrogen Oxide
1 Carbon Monoxide
2 Carbon
2 Carbon
2 Carbon Dioxide
3 Carbon Monoxide
3 Carbon Dioxide
3 Oxygen
4 Hydrogen Dioxide

Desired Results are as so:

1 Hydrogen Oxide
1 Carbon Monoxide
2 Carbon Dioxide
3 Carbon Monoxide
3 Oxygen
4 Hydrogen Dioxide

Comment: With your new sample data the code from both John and myself still return the desired output.

Comment: It Does Not... When I give the code a List of Sam, Ben, Benjamin, Ollie, Oliver and Samantha with ID's from 1 to 6 I still get the exact same list back? To add if the ids are the same it'll just take the largest there is no comparison as for LIKE in any of the code you have provided getting me both Samantha and Benjamin meaning Ollie and Oliver is supposedly LIKE Sam, Ben, Benjamin, Ollie, Oliver and Samantha if there is a like in your codes?

Comment: See my edits below. The new sample data is really no different than the original data and the code posted still returns what you state is the desired output. Help us understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Ended up figuring it out and using the following code:

```
SELECT D.RID, ProductID, D.Product, [Length] FROM 
(
SELECT RID, MAX([Length]) AS theLength 
FROM SortData GROUP BY RID
) AS X 
INNER JOIN SortData AS D ON D.RID = X.RID AND D.[Length] = X.theLength
WHERE D.Product LIKE Product
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query doesn't come close to your sample data and output. So I built this around the sample data provided to demonstrate one way of solving this.

```
declare @Something table
(
    Col1 int
    , Col2 varchar(20)
)

insert @Something values
(1, 'Sam')
, (1, 'Samantha')
, (2, 'Oliver')
, (3, 'Ollie')

select x.Col1
    , x.Col2
from
(
    select *
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Col1 order by LEN(Col2) desc)
    from @Something
) x
where x.RowNum = 1
```

**---EDIT---**

To demonstrate that this code still returns the desired output from your new sample data...

```
declare @Something table
(
    Col1 int
    , Col2 varchar(20)
)

insert @Something values
(1, 'Sam')
, (1, 'Samantha')
, (2, 'Oliver')
, (3, 'Ollie')
, (4, 'Benjamin')
, (4, 'Ben')

select x.Col1
    , x.Col2
from
(
    select *
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Col1 order by LEN(Col2) desc)
    from @Something
) x
where x.RowNum = 1
```

This returns:

```
1   Samantha
2   Oliver
3   Ollie
4   Benjamin
```

Since you claim this still doesn't work you need to provide an example of how or why this doesn't work. You keep mentioning LIKE but have not explained or demonstrated how that comes into play here. Help me understand the problem and I can help you find a solution.

Comment: I am trying to compare the two only if they are LIKE another string with the same id...

Comment: What does that mean? What would happen then if for Col1 you had two rows with 1 and col2 was Sean and Ollie? Do they both get returned? And how do you decide they are similar? What about Samantha and Sampson? Or those "like" each other? You need to explain the rules of the game.

Comment: Ok forget the example data try changing Oliver and Ollies ID's to 1... it doesn't compare them to see if they are similar.

Comment: Define what you mean by similar. What is the criteria to to know that Oliver and Ollie should be considered the same? And we can't forget the sample data, you need to fix it to demonstrate the problem. And what if they are the same length? Which one would get returned?

Comment: I will add more data, you are correct I would like the results as:                      1   Samantha
2   Oliver
3   Ollie
4   Benjamin but try changing your data to 1   Samantha
1  Oliver
1   Ollie
1   Benjamin and see what the results are... I have many Id's and relating data I posted simple data to make it easier to understand you have oversimplified the problem... and ignored my explanation...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps another option:   The `WITH TIES` clause in concert with `Row_Number()`

**Example**

```
Select Top 1 with ties * 
 From  YourTable
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition by ID Order By Len(Name) desc)
```

Comment: Nice John. I like that approach. Not sure I have seen that done like that before. :)

Comment: @SeanLange   I'm just a lazy, lazy man.  Only plus is there is no extra field.  Execution/Performance is the same as the cte.

Comment: No you aren't lazy. There is a huge difference between lazy and coding efficiently.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti The Main point of what I am asking is the Like my code drops the largest string already... Although this is a lot nice looking...